# Apex List Test Failing in Prod But Passes In Sandbox and if Directly Queried

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I have a simple getter inside my class that returns a list of cases depending on who the currently logged in user is (in my circumstance this is a Community User). When i run the code in my full sandbox, it passes with no issue, but the test fails when attempting to push to production. I am not using any @SeeAllData or anything else that would base data inconsistencies.

Additionally, if i directly run the same query in the getter within the context of the User within my System.RunAs() bracket, the list returns with the values intended.

What could be causing this strange error? I've never come across something like this where i can directly write the same query above the system.assert for the controller getter and get values where the getter iteself returns nothing. The `portalCases` query is literally the same and both are being invoked from the same context user, and it works/passes perfectly in my Staging org.

Controller Getter:

```
public List<Case> portalCases
    {
        get {
            if (portalCases == null)
            {
                portalCases = new List<Case>();
                portalCases = [SELECT Id, 
                                      AccountId, 
                                      Status, 
                                      RecordType.Name,
                                      Problem_Explanation__c,
                                      Patient_Name__c,
                                      Patient_DOB__c,
                                      Patient_MRN__c,
                                      Ordering_Physician__c,
                                      Web_Subject__c,
                                      Account.Name,
                                      CaseNumber,
                                      Collection_Date_Time__c,
                                      Affected_Tests__c,
                                      CreatedDate, 
                                      Description,
                                      CreatedBy.Name
                               FROM   Case
                               WHERE  (RecordType.Name = 'Problem Resolution' OR RecordType.Name = 'Web Inquiry')
                               AND    Account.Id IN :entitledCaseAccountIds];     

            }
            return portalCases;
        }
        set;
    }
```

Test Method (After all the other stuff):

```
System.RunAs(portalUser){
            TriCorePortalCaseController controller = new TriCorePortalCaseController();
            System.assert(controller.currentPortalUser != null); //this passes and it finds the user
            System.assert(!controller.entitledCaseAccountIds.isEmpty()); //this passes and finds the account ids permitted
            system.debug('Queried: ' +[SELECT Id, 
                                      AccountId, 
                                      Status, 
                                      RecordType.Name,
                                      Problem_Explanation__c,
                                      Patient_Name__c,
                                      Patient_DOB__c,
                                      Patient_MRN__c,
                                      Ordering_Physician__c,
                                      Web_Subject__c,
                                      Account.Name,
                                      CaseNumber,
                                      Collection_Date_Time__c,
                                      Affected_Tests__c,
                                      CreatedDate, 
                                      Description,
                                      CreatedBy.Name
                               FROM   Case
                               WHERE  (RecordType.Name = 'Problem Resolution' OR RecordType.Name = 'Web Inquiry')
                               AND    Account.Id IN :controller.entitledCaseAccountIds]); //this returns 2 cases as it should
            System.assert(!controller.portalCases.isEmpty());//This fails and returns an empty list. Why?
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run your test `with sharing`? Are the permissions for `Case` object, `AccountId` field,  and `Account` object the same across the two orgs?

Comment: Instead of using the runAs? RunAs documents it runs within sharing context of the user.

Comment: No, make your entire test class `with sharing`. Keep `runAs`.

Comment: Sorry tons of code. Still waiting for results of the deploy validation. Test passed as expected in Sandbox again.

Comment: Ah dang, you can only find out if it succeeds by deploying. That's tricky. What sharing modifier is applied to the controller itself?

Comment: So i added with sharing to the test class and attempted the deploy. Same result of an empty list. Even shows the list as queried in the debug logs but the direct call to the controller is still empty.

Comment: |USER_DEBUG|[47]|DEBUG|Queried: (Case:{Id=5003300000wsf7sAAA, AccountId=0013300001j6tcCAAQ, Status=New, RecordTypeId=01233000000IfrSAAS, CaseNumber=00401748, CreatedDate=2016-05-17 02:48:55, CreatedById=00540000002k55UAAQ}, Case:{Id=5003300000wsf7tAAA, AccountId=0013300001j6tcCAAQ, Status=New, RecordTypeId=01240000000IeTeAAK, Web_Subject__c=General, CaseNumber=00401749, CreatedDate=2016-05-17 02:49:04, Description=test, CreatedById=00540000002k55UAAQ})|USER_DEBUG|[71]|DEBUG|CalledFromController: ()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39871/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-cricketlang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the portal user has read access to the `Case` records. You might be able to make a `Case Sharing Rule` work. Failing that, you would need to use `Apex Sharing`. Unfortunately, if you create the record shares through triggers, you will need one each on `Case`, `Contact`, and `User` so that you match `$User.Contact.AccountId` to the `Case.AccountId`.

I've done similar sharing patterns before, and one useful concept was to create an `IdPair` class (in this case `User` to `Case`), so you can have one `Set<IdPair>` to insert, and one `Set<IdPair>` to delete.

Comment: Was definitely a sharing issue. All sharing is done with Apex Sharing, so i have a bit of work to do on getting all that taken care of, but this definitely explained the issues with the deployment.

Comment: I didnt even know about IdPair. lol.

Comment: Not sure if it's a common pattern, but it is useful for custom sharing.